# how to load m3u8 subtitles on videoview?

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

I'm making a live streaming application, but why an error? Even though I'm using the correct m3u8 file ...

This is my videoview code

```
final VideoView vd = new VideoView(OntvActivity.this);
vd.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
linear3.addView(vd);
vd.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));
addSubtitleSource(getSubtitleSource(srt),MediaFormat.createSubtitleFormat("text/srt",Locale.ENGLISH.getLanguage()));
vd.requestFocus();
vd.start();
```

And this is my inputstream code

```
private java.io.InputStream getSubtitleSource(String filepath) { java.io.InputStream ins = null; String ccFileName = filepath.substring(0,filepath.lastIndexOf('.'));
java.io.File file = new java.io.File(ccFileName);
if (file.exists() == false) {  } java.io.FileInputStream fins = null;
try { fins = new java.io.FileInputStream(file);
}catch (Exception e) {  } ins = (java.io.InputStream)fins; return ins; }
```